# How to align rotated objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I've been looking everywhere but don't know if a solutions exists for my problem:

In the image below, you can see two shapes.

I want to rotate the shape on the left so it matches the shape on the right, *without* repositioning the shape on the right in any way.

The problem I have run into is that Illustrator does not save the exact rotation angle of the object on the right. So, I cannot simply rotate the left object and then align.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to rotate it back and the align it directly on top of the other shape or do you want it merely nested above the shape?

Comment: @WELZ I need to rotate the left shape to the exact angle of the right shape, and then align the left directly on top of the right. If it helps to explain why I need to do this: I have multiple designs but 1 printing/cutting template, I want to be able to paste different designs onto the printing template and have them directly aligned on top of the old design, so the cut lines don't have to be recreated every time.

Comment: I'm also confused about something you wrote: Illustrator _does_ save the object rotation, I can grab a shape and rotate at a random angle, I can see in the properties panel the exact angle. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: why don't you delete the left shape and copy the right one!!  .. it seems to me identical..

Answer (score 1):

[Use symbols](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html).

- Create your graphics, select the objects and convert it to a symbol (Click the New Symbol button in the Symbols panel).
- Duplicate the symbol, rotate it to fit both shapes.

Next time you need to change the graphics, you only need to edit the symbol once.

Comment: This is a great solution. Instead of editing the existing symbol, you can also duplicate it then edit – and using the "replace symbol" option replace the artwork.